# How to call a method from inside an object?

Tags: redactor

I'm trying to modify a plugin I found for Redactor to get it working with the newest version, but my ignorance of JavaScript is keeping me from getting it working.

```
if (!RedactorPlugins) var RedactorPlugins = {};

RedactorPlugins.wordcount = function() {
    return {
        init: function() {
            var self = this;
            var $box = $(this.core.getBox());
            if ($box.length>0) {
                if ($box.find('.redactor-wordcount').length==0) {
                    var $wordcount_holder = $('#counter');

                    $box.on('keyup', function () {
                        $wordcount_holder.text('Words: ' + self.count());
                    });

                    $wordcount_holder.text('Words: ' + self.count());
                }
            }
        },

        count: function() {
            var html = this.get(),
                text = $(html).text().replace(/\t+/g, " ").replace(/\n/g, " ").replace(/\s+/g, " ");
            return text.split(' ').length - 1;
        }
    };
};
```

When I load the page an error is output saying `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. It's referring to the `count` function.

I was under the impression this syntax:

```
return {
...
}
```

Caused an object to be returned, but for some reason calling `self.count()` causes the above error to be thrown.

How can I call the `count` function from inside the `init` function?

EDIT: AS an aside, here is how Redactor plugins (for the new version of the software) are supposed to be defined:

```
if (!RedactorPlugins) var RedactorPlugins = {};

RedactorPlugins.myplugin = function()
{
    return {
        myMethod: function()
        {
            // your code
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: In general this code should work: http://jsfiddle.net/La197r68/ Seems like you have omitted something important

Comment: What is `this` when you call `init()`? You are using `this.core` and `this.get()`, but I don't see `core` or `get()` defined anywhere.

Comment: @aj_r I'm not sure. This probably is Redactor-specific. I'll remove the javascript & jquery tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that Redactor is calling `init()` with `this` pointing to some object that is different than what you expect. In order to call `count()`, you probably need to declare it before your `return` statement so you can use it in multiple places.

```
RedactorPlugins.wordcount = function() {

    // Declare count here, then remove 'this.' when you call it (see my comments below)
    var count = function() {
        var html = this.get(),
            text = $(html).text().replace(/\t+/g, " ").replace(/\n/g, " ").replace(/\s+/g, " ");
        return text.split(' ').length - 1;
    }

    return {
        init: function() {
            var self = this;
            var $box = $(this.core.getBox());
            if ($box.length>0) {
                if ($box.find('.redactor-wordcount').length==0) {
                    var $wordcount_holder = $('#counter');

                    $box.on('keyup', function () {
                        // Note the lack of 'this' here...
                        $wordcount_holder.text('Words: ' + count());
                    });
                    // ... and here
                    $wordcount_holder.text('Words: ' + count());
                }
            }
        },

        // Pass your count function as part of the return value
        // if you still want it to be accessible to whoever uses
        // the return value of this function.
        count: count
    };
};
```